# How to direct HTML links to siderbar items in R Shiny

Tags: javascript, html, r, shiny, rstudio

I am trying to add a HTML link in my Shiny dashboard. The ideal solution is to have users directed to a website by clicking items on the side bar. However, I could not find a solution to do so.

Here is my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

header <- dashboardHeader(
  title = "Test Dashboard"
)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu (
    menuItem("Test",startExpanded = TRUE,
             menuSubItem("Dashboard", tabName = "tab"),
             menuSubItem("Link")
    )
  )
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "tab",
            box(title = "Table", width = 10, status = "warning", DT::dataTableOutput("table"))
            )
  )
  )

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$table = DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(tabledata)
  })
}

shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1bwC.png) is the current sidebar layout.

Currently, I only show a datatable in the **Dashboard** tab, nothing in **Link** tab.

I am wondering if it is possible to have the user redirected to a website (https://shiny.rstudio.com/) by clicking the tabname **"Link"** on the sidebar.

I know the solution might be rendering the HTML link in **Server** and output in **UI**. Please advice.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see `?menuSubItem` it has a `href` argument:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

header <- dashboardHeader(
  title = "Test Dashboard"
)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu (
    menuItem("Test",startExpanded = TRUE,
             menuSubItem("Dashboard", tabName = "tab"),
             menuSubItem(text = "Link", href = "https://shiny.rstudio.com/")
    )
  )
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "tab",
            box(title = "Table", width = 10, status = "warning", DT::dataTableOutput("table"))
    )
  )
)

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

server <- function(input, output) {

  tabledata <- data.frame(replicate(10, sample(runif(10, 1, 10), rep=TRUE)))

  output$table = DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(tabledata)
  })
}

shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)
```